Forex data API endpoint that provide last closed candle's HLOC
As my title says, is there any data provider for Forex market that provides open,close,high and low of the last closed candle data.Most of the time I need 15Min candle data. I tested twelvedata and other similar endpoint. However, sometimes they jump an hour data or more in the response. If u kow any data provider with good data consistancey please help.

You can also check with Interactive Brokers

You can use Oanda's Rest-V20 API to achieve what you want, although you'll need to open either a Live or free Practice account and get an access token to do so.
I've been using this API for years now and have had no complaints about data consistency.
